# Coupon Code £5 off / £50 spent, £10 off / £100 spent (but not 10% off)

Tags: coupon, discount, coupon-codes

I want to make a single code which gives you £5 off per £50 spent...

So if you spend £250, you get £25/off however if you spend £220 then you only get £20 off. (Note that its not 10% off...)

Any thoughts on how to do this would be great

Thanks

Henry

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in a single rule by default. The Fooman Advanced Promotions extension lists this as a features but its currently unavailable.

To solve this within the out-of-the-box Magento setup you would need to setup multiple rules for each step. Specify the priority of the highest discount as the lowest:

for example:
The discount 200-250 => priority 10
The discount 150-200 => priority 11
The discount 100-150 => priority 12
etc.

Then set stop processing further rules to yes for every rule, this way only the highest discount will be added to the cart. Also don't forget to set the discount type to apply to the whole cart, otherwise the discount is gives for every product in the cart.